# what does this arg max notation mean in the scikit-learn docs for Naive Bayes?

Tags: math, machine-learning, scikit-learn, probability, naivebayes

I'm referring to the following page on Naive Bayes:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html

Specifically the equation beginning with y-hat. I think I generally understand the equations before that, but I don't understand the "arg max y" notation on that line. What does it mean?

Comment: None of the answers good enough to accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whereas the `max` of a function is the value of the output at the maximum, the `argmax` of a function is the value of the input ie the "argument" at the maximum.

[image: max vs argmax]

In the equation in your example:

[image]

`y_hat` is the value of `y`, ie the the class label, that maximizes the right hand expression.

Here `P(y)` is typically the proportion of class `y` in the training set, also called the "prior", and `P(x_i | y)` is the probability of observing the feature value `x_i` if the true class is indeed `y`, also called the "likelihood".

To understand the product `P(x_i | y)` better, consider an example where you are trying to classify a sequence of coin flips as coming from either coin `A` which lands heads in `50%` of training examples, or coin `B` which lands heads in `66.7%` of training examples. Here each individual `P(x_i | y_j)` is the probability of coin `y_j` (where `j` is either `a` or `b`) landing `x_i` (where `x_i` is either heads or tails).

```
Training set:

THH    A
HTT    A
HTH    A
TTH    A
HHH    B
HTH    B
TTH    B

Test set:

HHT    ?
```

So the sequence `HHT` has a `0.667*0.667*0.333 = 0.148` likelihood given coin `B`, but only a `0.5*0.5*0.5 = 0.125` likelihood given coin `A`. However we estimate a `57%` prior for coin `A` since `A` appears in `4/7` training examples, so we would end up predicting that this sequence came from coin `A`, since `0.57*0.125 > 0.43*0.148`. This is because we are more likely to start with coin `A`, so coin `A` has more chances to produce some less-likely sequences.

If the prior for coins `A` and `B` were `50%` each, then we would naturally predict coin `B` for `HHT`, since  this sequence clearly has the highest likelihood given coin `B`.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max):

> In mathematics, the **arguments of the maxima** (abbreviated **arg max** or **argmax**) are the points of the domain of some function at which the function values are maximized. In contrast to global maxima, referring to the largest outputs of a function, arg max refers to the *inputs*, or arguments, at which the function outputs are as large as possible.

In other words, `argmax f(x)` means the value of `x` (argument) that maximizes `f(x)`; understandably, it is frequently encountered in optimization problems (which underlie most machine learning algorithms).

Informally speaking, [`numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) is a similar function for Numpy arrays (i.e. not functions); it gives the *position* for which the array value is maximum:

```python
import numpy as np
x = np.array([3,1,8]) # maximum argument at position 2
np.argmax(x)
# 2
```